# Creating dynamic document type in Vespa

Tags: vespa

Like we can define index pattern in Elasticsearch and then keep on creating new indices with same mapping, is there any way to create dynamic document type in Vespa?

Our use case is - depending upon one of the keys' value, we need to put that in a specific document type. So, that while searching, we can search on specific document type according to that key's value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vespa has no dynamic document type support, document types needs to be configured explicitly in application package.

If you have 5M documents with key=foo, 500M documents with key=bar and 505M docs total, searching for key=foo will quickly restrict the search only those documents matching key=foo (5M).

Comment: E.g by using match:word and rank:filter on a indexed string field, or for an attribute field add fast-search (unless yourzs